# Saving the value of a custom field phone number in WooCommerce My account > Account details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, user-data

Trying to add a field for Woocommerce billing_phone to the **`my-account/edit-account/`**. It is present within the update address pages but when adding to the **`form-edit-account.php`** it does not update.

Currently adding by following the same code as the other fields, such as **`first_name`**:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--phone input-text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->billing_phone ); ?>" />
```

Image of form with **`billing_phone`** being shown as a value:

[image]

**But upon updating with new number it is not changed**…

How can I make this being saved/updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_save_account_details`** action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'my_account_saving_billing_phone', 10, 1 );
function my_account_saving_billing_phone( $user_id ) {
    $billing_phone = $_POST['billing_phone'];
    if( ! empty( $billing_phone ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $billing_phone ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on WooCommerce version 3+ and works. The data will be updated and displayed correctly.

---

Your complete billing phone field code in form-edit-account.php should be something like:

```html
<?php function field_phone(){
$user = wp_get_current_user(); 
 ?>
 <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--phone input-text" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->billing_phone ); ?>" />
</p> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked a treat!

Comment: This also worked for me. I combined it with [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742982/how-include-mask-in-the-woocommerce-fields-e-g-phone-99-9999-9999) to mask the phone number field.